# suspend and hibernate are both not working after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: suspend, dell, hibernate

Whenever I initiate a suspend or hibernate, the computers screen goes black. After 2 seconds it turns back on to the login screen... (DELL XPS 15)

```
apr 03 09:18:27 fredsco gnome-shell[2590]: Failed to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 03 10:27:35 fredsco gnome-shell[2590]: Failed to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 03 10:34:58 fredsco gnome-shell[2590]: Failed to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 03 10:36:34 fredsco gnome-shell[2590]: Failed to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 03 11:06:39 fredsco gnome-shell[2590]: Failed to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 03 18:46:59 fredsco gsd-media-keys[3360]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 03 18:46:59 fredsco gsd-power[3362]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 03 21:58:26 fredsco gnome-shell[3161]: Failed to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 04 07:13:48 fredsco gnome-shell[3161]: Failed to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 04 08:45:55 fredsco gnome-shell[3161]: Failed to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 04 08:46:34 fredsco gnome-shell[3161]: Failed to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 07 21:51:51 fredsco gsd-media-keys[2796]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 07 21:51:51 fredsco gsd-power[2798]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 08 13:03:07 fredsco gnome-shell[2611]: Failed to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 12 23:30:10 fredsco gsd-media-keys[2788]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 12 23:30:10 fredsco gsd-power[2792]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 13 09:40:45 fredsco gsd-media-keys[2792]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 13 09:40:45 fredsco gsd-power[2795]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 13 09:44:36 fredsco gnome-shell[2580]: Failed to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 13 10:42:02 fredsco gnome-shell[2580]: Failed to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 13 11:46:02 fredsco pipewire-media-session[2275]: pw.node: (bluez_output.34_28_40_18_03_7B.a2dp-sink-23) suspended -> error (Start error: Input/output error)
apr 13 11:46:31 fredsco pipewire-media-session[2275]: pw.node: (bluez_output.34_28_40_18_03_7B.a2dp-sink-23) suspended -> error (Start error: Input/output error)
apr 16 11:14:13 fredsco gsd-media-keys[2940]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 16 11:14:13 fredsco gsd-power[2943]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 16 18:13:55 fredsco gnome-shell[2753]: Failed to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 18 17:27:33 fredsco gsd-media-keys[2687]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 18 17:27:33 fredsco gsd-power[2688]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 18 18:08:08 fredsco gnome-shell[2450]: Failed to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 22 11:54:14 fredsco gsd-media-keys[2785]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 22 11:54:14 fredsco gsd-power[2787]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
apr 25 19:06:02 fredsco sudo[10170]:  fredsco : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/fredsco ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl suspend
apr 25 19:06:48 fredsco sudo[10906]:  fredsco : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/fredsco ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl stop nvidia-suspend.service
apr 25 19:07:00 fredsco sudo[10980]:  fredsco : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/fredsco ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl disable nvidia-suspend.service
```

Comment: Hibernate is by default disabled in Ubuntu. How did you enable it?

Comment: @vanadium https://www.lorenzobettini.it/2020/07/enabling-hibernation-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: As you changed the system, you will need to add that information to your question: use "edit".

Comment: Almost the same steps; https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10/?unapproved=3735277&moderation-hash=810e70432519282892fce69efb5e49af#comment-3735277

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also faced this same issue. I upgraded to 22.04 and hibernate stopped working. However my system is not Dell XPS, but I guess it's a common issue with ubuntu.
I faced a similar issue for Ubuntu 21.10 but I solved it by downgrading the Linux kernel.

After quite some searches I found out that it could be that the new kernel is not working well with your bios.

so **Option 1**: try downgrading to the kernel version your last ubuntu was running on.

**Option 2**: keep the current kernel version i.e  5.15 and try to update your Bios to the latest version. This could solve it.

**Option 3**: using `pm-hibernate` and `uswsusp`. This is what I did.

I enabled hibernation with this guide: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10/.
From this guide, I used the swapfile mechanism.

First I tried :
`sudo systemctl hibernate` to check if it worked. My computer would shutdown and start immediately and loose its state. So it dint work fully. Needed more fixes.

Next, I followed this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate#uswsusp and used the uswsusp option.

I installed pm-utils using

```
sudo apt install pm-utils
```

Then I downloaded and installed `uswsusp` from here : https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/uswsusp

Once you installed `uswsusp` , configure `pm-hibernate` to use `uswsusp` as mentioned in the guide above.

With this, I was able to hibernate my system using

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

This gives you an option to hibernate your system.

Comment: Thank you sudo pm-hibernate worked for me with the swapfile mechanism I already have!

Comment: I could not install `uswsusp`. I believe it's not available to ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: You can download it here: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/u/uswsusp/uswsusp_1.0+20120915-6.2_amd64.deb (with Chrome it could be possible you have to klick "Keep file" in your Downloads)

And then install with `sudo dpkg -i uswsusp_1.0+20120915-6.2_amd64.deb`

Answer (score 3):

For me the problem was that I couldnt wake the computer up again. I just got a black screen. Turning the computer off and on again worked, but was very annoying.
I updated my computer from 20.04 to 22-04 2 days ago. And I fixed the problem with:

- sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get upgrade
- reboot

Comment: worked flawlessly. Thanks

Comment: This really works!

Comment: whoa, I tried 5 different stack overflow answers and this is the one that actually worked! Thanks!